# Checking for multiple tags with SAXParser

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I don't know how to correctly phrase this question, but I'll show an example.

[image]

Assume I want to know the attribute `type` of the tag `block` I could just

```
 if (localName == "block") {

    int type = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("type));
```

However I also have different files that describe a blocktype itself, wich uses the < block > 
tags as base tags. I have to know if the attribute is a child from BOTH (Level/Blocktype) AND block.  Or maybe if it's under both LevelArray and Block.

I hope I'm making any sense, I don't know too much of Xml/xmlparsing.

-How do I look for attributes from elements nested inside other elements?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the state as you go. You could, for instance, have an instance variable called `inBlockTag` that is initially false. In the `startElement` method, if `localName.equals("block")` then you can set `inBlockTag` to true. Then as you process other elements, you can check the value of that flag to know if you're in a child of block or not. If you do this, don't forget to set it back to false on the endElement method (again, when `localName.equals("block")`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, then it appears that your problem is that how you process the `type` attribute actually depends on the structure of the actual node; in other words, how you process the `type` attribute depends on whether the `block` element has a parent 'LevelArray' or whether `block` itself is the document root element.

In this situation I think you need to implement your own simple state machine around the SAX callbacks. In other words, have some variable(s) that track what elements have already been opened and closed as the SAX parser traverses the XML file. This would be a very simple thing to do.

The alternative is to use a DOM parser, because the DOM parser gives you the power to obtain lists of children of given elements, etc. However, unless your requirements are very complex, I would stick with the SAX parser and just implement a state machine as suggested. The DOM parser is heavyweight in comparison and is more complicated to use.